# Facetime video "zoomed in" seemingly by default on macOS Mojave (10.14.3 )

Tags: macos, facetime

I have a weird issue on a Mac Mini running macOS Mojave (10.14.3) with the latest supplemental update (which I installed in the hopes of fixing this issue).

When I start a Facetime call, the picture I get back from my friends are extremely zoomed in; but in their thumbnail preview on their device, they look normal.

If I press Fullscreen on the call and then exit Fullscreen, this issue fixes itself. But it's annoying to have to do every time.

Here is an example of what I get versus what they are sending:

[image: Screenshot of an example of what I get versus what they are sending.]

Comment: Well, macOS Mojave now has been bumped up to 10.14.5 (and even 10.14.4) before that, so perhaps running those updates would help? Here is a link to [the combo updater for macOS 10.14.5](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2000?locale=en_US) on Apple’s website.

Comment: Thanks Jake, actually the issue only exists on this one device; none of my other identical machines have this issue; so I'm hoping it's just a setting that's gone bad on the one machine.

Comment: Well, if that is the case I would strongly recommend you download [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) and use it to do some deep cache cleaning on your Mac. I won’t hurt anything and might clear things up.